# PGP block size differs when encrypting in K9

Tags: java, android, encryption, openpgp, openkeychain

I am using K9 and Openkeychain to encrypt emails. One odd thing that I found was how the size of the pgp block differs when same text is encrypted using two different methods. Method A involves writing the text "This is a test" in K9 and signing and encrypting the email and sending it. The following is the keyblock for method A:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
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=Elaq
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Method B involves using the Encrypt/Decrypt feature of Openkeychain and copying and pasting the encrypted data into K9 and sending a normal mail. The PGP block for method B is:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
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=Ok9n
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Can anyone explain why the PGP block almost doubles when using K9?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this not related to programming. This question might be better suited for [android.se] or [su].

Comment: so writing a program to encrypt text is not related to programming???

Comment: @IminderSingh I've voted to leave it open, but without the code we cannot see what arguments / configuration you are using. It's not surprising that ArtjomB voted to close it if you look at it that way. Show us the code!

Comment: the code is in k9 and openkeychain repositories : [link] (https://github.com/open-keychain/openpgp-api) [link] (https://github.com/k9mail/k-9)